# SQL Server: How to create hierarchy combinations from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, hierarchy

I have the levels of a hierarchy stacked in one table and I want to create the combinations. I tried to use recursive queries, but I could not figure it out. I am sure there must be an easy way to do this. I have different hierarchies with different number of levels, so I don't want to write a code for each and I want to have a query that handles the number of the levels. I would appreciate any help!

Here is the code to create the sample data:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [tmp].[tblSample](
    [hier] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [lvl] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA00010102', N'3', 3)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA00019999', N'3', 4)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA00020107', N'3', 6)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA00029999', N'3', 7)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA11810001', N'3', 9)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA11812087', N'3', 10)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA11852299', N'3', 12)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA1185', N'2', 12)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA', N'1', 12)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA1181', N'2', 10)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA', N'1', 10)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA1181', N'2', 9)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA', N'1', 9)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA0002', N'2', 7)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA', N'1', 7)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA0002', N'2', 6)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA', N'1', 6)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA0001', N'2', 4)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA', N'1', 4)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA0001', N'2', 3)
GO
INSERT [tmp].[tblSample] ([hier], [lvl], [id]) VALUES (N'AA', N'1', 3)
GO
```

This is the query that I generated my desired result for this specific hierarchy:

```
SELECT t1.hier, t2.hier, t3.hier FROM tblSample t1 
    INNER JOIN tblSample t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t2.lvl=t1.lvl+1 
    INNER JOIN tblSample t3 ON t1.id=t3.id  AND t3.lvl=t1.lvl+2
```

**sample data:**

[image]

**desired result:**

[image]

Comment: You have the data already in hierarchical structure and the result you want may not be achieved by hierarchical query rather a join how you did already . I see a scope of `PIVOT` usage based on level too.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I have other hierarchy tables that have 5 or more levels. The sample that I posted had 3, how can I write joins that can work regardless of number of levels?

Comment: yes I understood your point in the first place. Because of the column list depends on the `lvl` you have I am not sure about a generalized query but how about using pivot and give a maximum of level to `PIVOT` ? Can't we give a maximum `lvl` of 10 or so... ?

Comment: Look at the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32c002509c6b2885c117941b6092b3a5. and let me know

Comment: Did the `PIVOT` one help ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 it is almost there, I am struggling with the columns that are generated with NULLs, I need to remove them from the result since I am using a max 10 levels to cover all of the hierarchies

Comment: Ahh. Are you talking about columns with completely null or the columns having partially null because in later case we could further use max on the result set where as in former you may need dynamic pivoting ( not much familiar though). Many examples are there I can see in SO.

Comment: @Ibo...thanks for asking. I did now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just looks like conditional aggregation to me:

```
select max(case when lvl = 1 then hier end),
       max(case when lvl = 2 then hier end),
       max(case when lvl = 3 then hier end)
from tblSample
group by id;
```

Alternatively, you can phrase this as joins:

```
select s.hier, s2.hier, s3.hier
from tblSample s join
     tblSample s2
     on s2.lvl = s.lvl + 1 and
        s2.id = s.id join
     tblSample s3
     on s3.lvl = s2.lvl + 1 and
        s3.id = s2.id
where s.lvl = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=250fe3240fc7e1db9b55ac1219b939c2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: is there a way to make the aggregation method dynamic so that it recognizes the number of levels itself and returns that many columns?

Comment: @Ibo . . . You would need to use dynamic SQL.  It is pretty easy to modify the first query to be dynamic.  You might want to ask another question, though.

Answer (score 1):

We can also make use of `PIVOT` but again we have to provide a certain maximum `level` in the pivoting clause and to make it dynamic, you need to think of converting it to `Dynamic Sql` (Unfortunately I am not much familiar with SQL server dynamic SQL)

```
select id
      ,[1] as hier1
      ,[2] as hier2
      ,[3] as hier3
from 
(
  select t1.hier,t1.lvl,t1.id
  from tblsample t1
) src
pivot
(
  max(hier)
  for lvl in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9feea2cd27019c9a48037aa49c0e0e5f)</kbd>